# Facebook - Embed posts from public-open group on my website

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to print on my website all posts from my opened and publish group? I tried with that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts but when I paste a url to group's post, this script print an error which say - This post is unavailable (...).

Is it possible to print this posts on my website if I have a post ID and group ID?

Comment: I use Facebook PHP SDK to get all informations about posts so I would like to continue do that in the same way.

Comment: Well in this case, take a look at the page again: **Only public posts from Facebook Pages and profiles can be embedded.**

Answer (score 0):

You can´t use it for groups, as you can read in the docs:

> Only public posts from Facebook Pages and profiles can be embedded.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts

You would need to create your own App for that, here´s the endpoint to get group posts: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/group/feed